# Filtering data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my database I have a post entity connected to category entity.
I display the categories on my website using `<p>$row_category['categoryname']</p>`. I want to make them hyperlinks which will display the post in the chosen category. How to achieve that?

Comment: You have to set category name as parameter of GET and user filter in query in DB with this parameter to get filtered posts.
Example:
<a href="posts.php?cat=<?php echo $row_category['categoryname'] ?>"><?php echo $row_category['categoryname']?> <a/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use some sort of identifier for the categories that is then looked up by the destination PHP and passed via GET. Then just wrap it in an `<a>`

```
<p><a href="handler.php?id=$row_category['categoryid']">$row_category['categoryname']</a></p>
```

In handler.php you would retrieve the `id` with:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="desired link"><?php echo $row_category['categoryname']; ?></a>
```

I guess this what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

or in other way we can do same

```
<?php echo "<a href='goto.html'>".$row_category['categoryname']."</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: `goto.html` will fail, unless Apache is told to run `.html` as PHP. Refer to [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22747347/)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using mySQL, so this should work.

```
<?php
while ($row_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
    <a href="desired link"><?php echo $row_category["categoryname"]; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

might i suggest you start on PDO, now when mySQL are getting outdated. :)

Comment: OP tagged as `mysql`, doesn't necessarily mean is using `mysql_*` functions, but your answer does. Just because a car's gas cap is open and smells like gas, doesn't mean the tank is full, right? ;-)